# Website menu 2 levels deep, different stacking on desktops and mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a menu for a website. It has 2 levels. You can click on the title of the section and then the links for this section show up, while the other sections hide. Simple enough.

[image: View on desktop]

Now, the problem is that the mobile view is quite different. It works the same, but the sections are displayed first as a list, and the section links (whichever is currently shown) are displayed below. Like so:

[image: View on mobile]

I've managed to do it like that using Bootstrap (striped the unnecessary code):

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-12">
        Section 1 title
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 hidden-xs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link in section 1</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-12">
        Section 2 title
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 hidden-xs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link in section 2</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row visible-xs">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link in section 1</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link in section 2</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

It works. But I would like to avoid having to create the subsection twice. Also the section titles are not displayed as a list, instead they're "cheated" as columns in the grid.

Comment: i can use the flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>link in section 1</li>
  <li>link in section 1</li>
  <li>link in section 1</li>
  <li>link in section 1</li>
  <li>link in section 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, thanks for the answer, but I don't seem to understand how that solves my problem. Yes, the list items are displayed as a centered list, which you can do by just specifying: `ul { text-align: center; } li { display: inline-block; }` rather than using flexbox. But it doesn't solve the problem of different stacking on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only two columns and make `<ul>` wider  than its column on a narrow screen.

[image: layout]

I've used standard [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) and `col-xs-6 col-sm-12` class instead of `col-xs-6 col-lg-12`.

And I've painted backgrounds on a narrow screen to make the layout visualization.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/9oo7bvrw/

```js
var listFirst  = $('#list-1');
var listSecond = $('#list-2');

listFirst.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  listSecond.collapse('hide');
})
listSecond.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  listFirst.collapse('hide');
})
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* The heart of the matter */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #list-1, 
  #list-2 {
    width: 100vw !important;
  }
  #list-1 {
    margin-right: -50vw;
  }
  #list-2 {
    margin-left: -50vw;
  }
  .col-xs-6 {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

/* Visualization */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-xs-6:first-child {
    background: #69c;
  }
  .col-xs-6:last-child {
    background: #c69;
  }
  #list-1, 
  #list-2 {
    background: #9c6;
  }
  a, 
  a:hover, 
  a:focus {
    color: white;
  }
}

/* Decorations */
.container {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #list-1, 
  #list-2 {
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #list-1 li, 
  #list-2 li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#list-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="list-1">Section 1 title</a>
      <ul class="collapse" id="list-1">
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#list-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="list-2">Section 2 title</a>
      <ul class="collapse" id="list-2">
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link in section 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```